# R DataTables do not display Buttons above tabel

Tags: r, datatables, r-markdown, dt

I have problem with the tabels in HTML file after rendering. They are displayed on the both sides of the tabel (in the way that is presented in the attached [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs7oJ.png)). What could be done to force the buttons to be displayed above the tabel and not on both sides of it?

I have also checked dom =  ['frtBip'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXew0.png) and dom = ['<B>frtip'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAO94.png)  options and achived results like in the pictures.

```
datatable(data_tabel,
          extensions = c("Buttons","KeyTable"), options = list(
               dom = 'Bfrtip',
               buttons = list('copy', 'print', list(
                 extend = 'collection',
                 buttons = list(
                   list(extend = c('csv'), filename = 'BPTrait'),
                   list(extend = c('excel'), filename = 'BPTrait'),
                   list(extend = c('pdf'), filename = 'BPTrait')
                   ),
                 text = 'Download'
               )),
               keys = T
               ),
          rownames=F,
          colnames = c("Variant ID","Protein","Trait","-log10(p-value)"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this ?

[image]

```
library(DT)
dtable <- datatable(iris,
                    extensions = c("Buttons","KeyTable"), 
                    options = list(
                      dom = '<"top"B>frtip',
                      buttons = list('copy', 'print'),
                      keys = T
                    ),
                    rownames=F)

library(htmltools)
htmlwidgets::prependContent(
  dtable,
  tags$style(HTML(".top {display:flex}"))
)
```

Or centered?

[image]

```
library(htmltools)
htmlwidgets::prependContent(
  dtable,
  tags$style(HTML(".top {display: flex; justify-content: center;}"))
)
```

Comment: Yes, I have extactly the tabel like in the first example. With the Copy, Print on the left above and Search on the right. Even with the code provided by you I have Copy and Print on the left above and search on the right but apart from tabel

Comment: @okraw Is it in a RMarkdown document?

Comment: HTML build from RMarkdown

Comment: @okraw Could you provide the RMarkdown code? By the way your `buttons` option is not correctly written.